# Struggling with beliefs in miracles

Tags: miracles

In the quran there are miracles like turning a stick into a snake, splitting a sea, reviving dead people or whatever else you can think of. I'm really struggling to believe in this and need to understand something about them.

These miracles if claimed by anyone know they would be deemed a madman, I also tried and I can not find a single piece of evidence to back them up. To me it just seems like another myth or metaphorical story not true.

Its also just weird to me how miracles go on throughout history and as soon as human civilisation builds technology to convey messages and record things with ease and effectively the miracles completely stop.

Some people may say that you have to trust Allah and your knowledge is limited or this is a test. Believing in something with little to no evidence just generally seems wrong to me and you can say life is a test but that cant be the answer to everything you have. An answer like that is probably the reason why a lot of ex-Muslims left Islam as they may have questioned themselves only to receive such an answer.

Are the stories in Quran tales, metaphors or do we actually take them literally and what evidence is there to back them up?

Comment: What do you mean by "evidence"? If Allah telling you about them isn't enough evidence for you, I don't really know what else you could want.

Comment: @TheZ that is part of my struggle I am failing to believe what I am being told because it sounds so unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok dont believe you have not seen with your eyes. But there are many things which you can see or observe
Prophet Muhammad SAW said When you hear that [a plague] is in a land, do not go to it and if it occurs in a land that you are already in, then do not leave it, fleeing from it.

Countries didnt believe it and called citizens from china during Covid-19. And you have seen the results.

Technology actually proves miracles exists like Allah says i will show you what you did in life. How Allah will show us technology gives us idea through camera. Now everybody captures pictures and make videos to capture the moments of their lives.

Most non believers say if Allah knows that humans will commit crimes and go to hell then why HE created humans because they will do sins. Technology gives us smart contract and machine learning concepts. Smart contracts we create in blockchain technology which perform certain tasks in particular situations. Machine learning algorithm learns from its experience and perform tasks. This has lot of similarity with humans creation. Humans learn throughout his life and choose good or bad as per his experience so he has choice and on the basis of his selection he will be rewarded or punished and not just a hard and fast rule.

Miracle evidence: In quran Allah says "Today We will preserve (save) your body so you can be a Sign for people who come after you. Surely many people are heedless of Our Signs. "AL-QURAN 10;92". His body discovered and displayed in Egypt museum few hundred years ago which Quran has mentioned 1400 years back. So its a miracle anyone can see if any doubts.

Mostly problem with Muslims who are leaving Islam which i dont think very high in numbers is they just read but dont try to explore or understand. Science agrees on 80% quran and 20% still undiscovered. Gog magog example i usually give is the one. These are from Prophet Noah descendants and more than us in numbers and living on earth but still undiscovered.

Comment: Youre assuming that those people dont do research but what I try to do is unbiased research for the miracle evidence you gave there was another pharaoh that scientists claimed it couldve been. The statistic of what science agrees on Ive not come across that much aside from Zakir Naik repeatedly saying it. Also the disease thing you mentioned at the top doesnt refer to Covid-19. The examples of technology doesnt fit very well as there is no punishment after the technology failed or did something bad the only thing that happens is they get thrown out pretty much every piece of equipment does.

Comment: Ok please then  can you explain what type of disease refered in that hadith. Paraoh body was scientifically proven by highly qualified experts one of them Dr. Moasres (not muslim) from France research (book Qur’an, Bible and Science). For disbelievers Quran says "Do they not travel through the land, so that their hearts (and minds) may thus learn wisdom and their ears may thus learn to hear? Truly it is not their eyes that are blind, but their hearts which are in their breasts" Al-Haj (22:46)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't believe what Allah is saying to you then you are far too gone astray. You are simply a none-believer. If you don't believe in Allah's wording then why would you even believe what we say? and why are you even on this site?

And as per your statement "*...I am failing to believe what I am being told because it sounds so unrealistic.*" Are you seriously doubting Allah's powers !! He is AL-MALIK (The King and Owner of Dominion), AL-AZEEZ (The All-Mighty), AL-MUTAKABBIR (The Supreme, The Majestic), AL-KHAALIQ (The Creator, The Maker), AL-KABEER (The Greatest), AL-MAJEED    (The Glorious), AL-MUBDI    (The Originator), AL-MUHYEE (The Giver of Life), MAALIK-UL-MULK (Master of the Kingdom). Our believing and dis-believing comes from our brain which He (Allah) created and our brain is too incompetent to even understand him.

I just pray to Allah that He shows you the right path and clears your thoughts that are leading you astray.

Jazak-Allah.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean by asking this question as a converted one to Islam.
The problem is not with miracles, but the perception that you and all humanity is 'eating' everyday.
If you really want to understand Quran, religion, why Islam is the Truth, you have to understand concept of 'La ilaha illa Allah', Tawheed. So, for people who do not understand or struggle believing in miracles, I suggest watching these video series. It is in Turkish but with english subtitles. I was muslim already when I have found these videos, but have similar struggles, but suddenly the ideas, questions, approaches here woke me up. I hope you will be guided by Hadee Allah.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU87-1e5Ekw&list=PLD4cFlbKVT9eY5lDVETqE-W-IlTF98slg&index=2